# How to disable automatically generated comments in node, but enable programmatically created comments?

Tags: views, 6, comments

I decided to programatically print comments un Views using PHP footer. The problem is that they now appears twice (my code + default). When I disable comments in content type settings, both disappear. How can I disable the default comments and keep my comments printed by php code? I tried to edit node.tpl file. but there is no section responsible for showing comments there (I use Garland).I do this because I am using a complicated views structure and I would like the comments to be displayed below the node, but not at the end of the whole view. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Configure comments to be show in separate page, and you'll be able to show them with your view. Also, you've to hide the comment link if you do it.